# How can i edit the Li item to add text to it with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a trello like web app for practising so i have completed the cards with drag drop features but i want now to add content to the li items of an ul tag that can even be edited by user too

I  want it to be in javascript

HTML COde

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Trello</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Masthead -->
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="boards-menu">
            <div class="board-search">
                <input type="search" class="board-search-input" aria-label="Board Search">
                <i class="fas fa-search search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><i class="fab fa-trello logo-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Trello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="user-settings" style="height: 20px;margin-bottom:35px;">
            <a href="profile.html">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/settings.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Lists container -->
    <section class="lists-container">
        <div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
            <h3 class="list-title">Tasks to Do</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list" id="dragabble_card1">
            <h3 class="list-title">Completed Tasks</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
            <h3 class="list-title">Tasks to Do</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add-list-btn btn">Add a list</button>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script.js">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#parent, #parent1").sortable({
        connectWith: ".list-items"
    }).disableSelection();
});


document.getElementById('button').onclick = repeat;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('repeatTHIS');


function repeat() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "repeatTHIS" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

my css as  follows

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font: inherit;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

:focus {
    outline-color: #fa0;
}

:root {
    font-size: 11px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Masthead */

.masthead {
    flex-basis: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.8rem;
    margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;
    background-color: #0067a3;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.masthead .btn {
    background-color: #4c94be;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
}

.masthead .btn:hover {
    background-color: #3385b5;
}

.boards-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.boards-btn {
    flex-basis: 9rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 0.8rem;
    padding: 0.6rem 0.8rem;
}

.boards-btn-icon {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    padding-right: 1.2rem;
}

.board-search {
    flex-basis: 18rem;
    position: relative;
}

.board-search-input {
    height: 3rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    background-color: #4c94be;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3rem 0 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.board-search-input:hover {
    background-color: #66a4c8;
}

.search-icon {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0.8rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    color: #fff;
}

.logo {
    flex: 1;
    font-family: "Courgette", cursive;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin: 0 2rem;
    transition: color 150ms;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.logo-icon {
    padding-right: 0.4rem;
}

.user-settings {
    display: flex;
    height: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
}


.user-settings-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 3.5rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
}


/* Board info bar */

.board-info-bar {
    flex-basis: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0.8rem 0;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: #f6f6f6;
}

sboard-info-bar .btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
    padding: 0 0.6rem;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

.board-info-bar .btn:hover {
    background-color: #006aa8;
}

.private-btn-icon,
.menu-btn-icon {
    padding-right: 0.6rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.board-title h2 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Lists */

.lists-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 2.4rem;
}

.lists-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #66a3c7;
    border: 0.8rem solid #0079bf;
    border-top-width: 0;
}

.lists-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    padding: 0 0.8rem 0.8rem;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 8.6rem);
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.list {
    flex: 0 0 27rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #e2e4e6;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 11.8rem);
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.list:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.list-title {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.list-items {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: start;
    padding: 0 0.6rem 0.5rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.list-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1.6rem;
}

.list-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #c4c9cc;
    border-right: 0.6rem solid #e2e4e6;
}

.list-items li {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.3;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0.65rem 0.6rem;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list-items li:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-items li:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.add-card-btn {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #838c91;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add-card-btn:hover {
    background-color: #cdd2d4;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.add-list-btn {
    flex: 0 0 27rem;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #006aa7;
    color: #a5cae0;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.add-list-btn:hover {
    background-color: #005485;
}

.add-card-btn::after,
.add-list-btn::after {
    content: '...';
}



    $(function () {
        $("#parent, #parent1").sortable({
            connectWith: ".list-items"
        }).disableSelection();
    });


    document.getElementById('button').onclick = repeat;

    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('repeatTHIS');


    function repeat() {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "repeatTHIS" + ++i;
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .btn {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font: inherit;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        color: inherit;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    :focus {
        outline-color: #fa0;
    }

    :root {
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Masthead */

    .masthead {
        flex-basis: 4rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 0.8rem;
        margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;
        background-color: #0067a3;
        box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .masthead .btn {
        background-color: #4c94be;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        transition: background-color 150ms;
    }

    .masthead .btn:hover {
        background-color: #3385b5;
    }

    .boards-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .boards-btn {
        flex-basis: 9rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 0.8rem;
        padding: 0.6rem 0.8rem;
    }

    .boards-btn-icon {
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        padding-right: 1.2rem;
    }

    .board-search {
        flex-basis: 18rem;
        position: relative;
    }

    .board-search-input {
        height: 3rem;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        background-color: #4c94be;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 3rem 0 1rem;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .board-search-input:hover {
        background-color: #66a4c8;
    }

    .search-icon {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0.8rem;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
        color: #fff;
    }

    .logo {
        flex: 1;
        font-family: "Courgette", cursive;
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        margin: 0 2rem;
        transition: color 150ms;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .logo:hover {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }

    .logo-icon {
        padding-right: 0.4rem;
    }

    .user-settings {
        display: flex;
        height: 1.5rem;
        color: #fff;
    }


    .user-settings-btn {<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Trello</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Masthead -->
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="boards-menu">
            <div class="board-search">
                <input type="search" class="board-search-input" aria-label="Board Search">
                <i class="fas fa-search search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><i class="fab fa-trello logo-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Trello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="user-settings" style="height: 20px;margin-bottom:35px;">
            <a href="profile.html">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/settings.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Lists container -->
    <section class="lists-container">
        <div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
            <h3 class="list-title">Tasks to Do</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list" id="dragabble_card1">
            <h3 class="list-title">Completed Tasks</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
            <h3 class="list-title">Tasks to Do</h3>
            <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add-list-btn btn">Add a list</button>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script.js">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        width: 3.5rem;
        margin-right: 1.5rem;
    }


    /* Board info bar */

    .board-info-bar {
        flex-basis: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0.8rem 0;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        color: #f6f6f6;
    }

    sboard-info-bar .btn {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        transition: background-color 150ms;
        padding: 0 0.6rem;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        height: 3rem;
    }

    .board-info-bar .btn:hover {
        background-color: #006aa8;
    }

    .private-btn-icon,
    .menu-btn-icon {
        padding-right: 0.6rem;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .board-title h2 {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /* Lists */

    .lists-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 2.4rem;
    }

    .lists-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #66a3c7;
        border: 0.8rem solid #0079bf;
        border-top-width: 0;
    }

    .lists-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: start;
        padding: 0 0.8rem 0.8rem;
        overflow-x: auto;
        height: calc(100vh - 8.6rem);
        margin-top: 60px;
    }

    .list {
        flex: 0 0 27rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #e2e4e6;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 11.8rem);
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        margin-right: 1rem;
    }

    .list:last-of-type {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .list-title {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #333;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .list-items {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-content: start;
        padding: 0 0.6rem 0.5rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .list-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 1.6rem;
    }

    .list-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #c4c9cc;
        border-right: 0.6rem solid #e2e4e6;
    }

    .list-items li {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.3;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0.65rem 0.6rem;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .list-items li:last-of-type {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .list-items li:hover {
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    .add-card-btn {
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #838c91;
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .add-card-btn:hover {
        background-color: #cdd2d4;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }


    .add-list-btn {
        flex: 0 0 27rem;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        background-color: #006aa7;
        color: #a5cae0;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 150ms;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .add-list-btn:hover {
        background-color: #005485;
    }

    .add-card-btn::after,
    .add-list-btn::after {
        content: '...';
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Trello</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Masthead -->
        <header class="masthead">
            <div class="boards-menu">
                <div class="board-search">
                    <input type="search" class="board-search-input" aria-label="Board Search">
                    <i class="fas fa-search search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><i class="fab fa-trello logo-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Trello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="user-settings" style="height: 20px;margin-bottom:35px;">
                <a href="profile.html">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/settings.png">
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Lists container -->
        <section class="lists-container">
            <div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
                <h3 class="list-title">Tasks to Do</h3>
                <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                    <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
            </div>
            <div class="list" id="dragabble_card1">
                <h3 class="list-title">Completed Tasks</h3>
                <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                    <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
            </div>
            <div class="list" id="dragabble_card">
                <h3 class="list-title">Tasks to Do</h3>
                <ul class="list-items" id="parent">
                    <li id="repeatTHIS"> </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="add-card-btn btn" id="button" onclick="repeat()">Add a card</button>
            </div>
            <button class="add-list-btn btn">Add a list</button>
        </section>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="script/script.js">

        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the HTML **Attribute** called `contenteditable`, this will allow the users to edit html content on the element!
But if you need to save the changes, you have to add some javascript `AJAX` request into your `PHP` page that may save the changes into a database or a file or whatever else.
Hope my answer would be useful for you!

```js
window.isEditingALi=false;

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){ //Of course you can merge this EventListener with the next one but I am separing them just to make things clear for you !

  const elementsIdSelector="editableLi";

  e=(e||window.event);
  e.preventDefault();
  const path=e.path;
  for(var i=0;i<path.length-4;i++){
    if(path[i].tagName=="LI"&&path[i].id==elementsIdSelector){
      //Found a Li element with the id required ( Even dynamically created li would fires ! )
      
      //Do whatever you want there 
      
      path[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
          if(this.getAttribute("contenteditable")!="true"){
            const wantEdit=window.confirm("You want to edit this element content ?");
            if(wantEdit){
              this.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
              window.isEditingALi=this;
              this.focus();
             }else{
              window.isEditingALi=false;
             }
          }
        });
      
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e=(e||window.event);
  e.preventDefault();
  const path=e.path;
  let canGetReset=true;
  for(var i=0;i<path.length-4;i++){
    if(path[i]==window.isEditingALi) canGetReset=false;
  }
  if(canGetReset&&window.isEditingALi){
    window.isEditingALi.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
    
    //Here you can add your Ajax request or whatever function you want to do after the user finish editing the li ..
    
    alert("Li has been changed successfully !");
    window.isEditingALi=false;
    
  }
});


//This is just an additional function to test if the dynamically created element would work or not !

function createEditableLi(){
  const ul=document.querySelector("ul");
  const newLi=document.createElement("li");
        newLi.setAttribute("id", "editableLi");
        newLi.innerHTML="New Li (Created dynamically)";
  ul.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```css
body{

  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}
```

```html
You can actually edit these Li by clicking and apply any changes you want ! (Even dynamically created elements are supported now!)
<br>
<ul>
  <li id="editableLi"> First Li</li>
  <li id="editableLi"> Second Li</li>
  <li id="editableLi"> Third Li</li>
  <li id="editableLi"> Another Li</li>
  <li id="editableLi"> More Li</li>
</ul>

<br>
<button onclick="createEditableLi()">Create a New Li Dynamically</button>
```

Comment: whrn creating li items dynimically then the editing functionality is not working on it can you tell me why it is so

Comment: Because my code works only with already created elements, I will modifie it into a better version so it can works for dynamically created elements too!
Give me a second please ..

Comment: Here we go I have **edited** the snippet now it works even with new elements !